# How is 'return new Error' different from 'throw'

Tags: javascript, promise, return, throw

I was practicing promise and this exercise popped up. I knew the `throw` will immediately hop out of the the function and find the nearest `.catch`. However, I still don't understand why `return new Error('test');` is followed by the action of `.then` and not `.catch`.

Code snippet

```
function job(state) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (state) {
            resolve('success');
        } else {
            reject('error');
        }
    });
}

let promise = job(true);

promise

.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    return job(true);
})

.then(function(data) {
    if (data !== 'victory') {
        throw 'Defeat';
    }

    return job(true);
})

.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})

.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);

    return job(false);
})

.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    return job(true);
})

.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);

    return 'Error caught';
})

.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    return new Error('test');
})

.then(function(data) {
    console.log('Success:', data.message);
})

.catch(function(data) {
    console.log('Error:', data.message);
});
```

The result

```
> "success"
> "Defeat"
> "error"
> "Error caught"
> "Success:" "test"
```

I have researched but I can't seem to find any explanation on this matter. I also consulted chatGPT but it really sucked.

Comment: The difference is: when you are returning an Error, you are keeping the stacktrace operating normally. But when you throw an Error, it travels up the stacktrace until being caught (Promise implicitly catches the error)

Comment: Returning an `Error` is no different than returning an `Object` or a `string` or something - it's just some data. Yeah, you explicitly call it an `Error`, but since you aren't telling Javascript to treat it as such it just assumes your method actually needed to return that. Like, what if your promise is something like `ResolveToErrorMessage`, would you expect it to _resolve_ in the `catch` block? It's kind of stupid, but it keeps things versatile enough.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on "stacktrace operating normally"? I thought Promise implicitly catches the error long as the Error occurs

Comment: @LamMyKy-Kailey Point is there is no error (exception) *occurring*. It's just an object that is being created, until it is `throw`n - but it isn't.